# MVC Pattern in Web App (JSP Language)

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp

Hello i am developing a web app...i am using MVC architecture in my design.
i have one form add_Flat.jsp in which admin enter the flat details and it will be stored in database (MS-Access) no other jsp page would be open on submit button.just a message displayed on add_Flat.jsp.

How can i achieve this by using MVC pattern ? do i have to write different servlet for every jsp page ? and model class for database connectivity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How can i achieve this by using MVC pattern ?*

Let the form submit to a servlet which sets the message in the request scope and forwards back to the JSP.

---

> *do i have to write different servlet for every jsp page ?*

Not necessarily. You can write a single servlet which acts as a front controller, or just use an existing MVC framework like JSF, Spring MVC, etc.

---

> *and model class for database connectivity ?*

A model class should not be aware about any DB connectivity. A model class should be a simple Javabean class.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Contains Hello World examples and links to in-depth answers on servlet related questions here.